# How can I subset rows in a data frame in R if any value in one row match values in a vector?

Tags: r, subset

I have dataset named DF1, which like this:

```
 V1    V2    V3   V4     V5    V6
A01N  A01N  A01P  Null  Null  Null
C09K  A61K  C09D  C08K  Null  Null                                              
A61K  A61P  A61P  A61K  A61K  A61K                                          
A01D  A01D  A01D  A01D  A01D  Null
E06A  Null  Null  Null  Null  Null
```

also a vector named V:

```
(A01N C09K A01D)
```

What I want is that subset DF1 based on the vector elements, if one row in DF1 have the elements in V, no matter in which column, then keep the row. if not, drop it. The result should be:

```
 V1    V2    V3   V4     V5    V6
A01N  A01N  A01P  Null  Null  Null
C09K  A61K  C09D  C08K  Null  Null
```

I try to use subset(): test_t1 <- subset(DF1, **DF1[,1:6]** %in% V)

but I just know how to subset one column or row, how to handle multiple column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `reshaping` using `tidyverse` functions. You format columns to long to then compare with the vector of values. After that, filter and then reshape to wide. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
vec <- c('A01N','C09K','A01D')
#Code
new <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  mutate(Flag=+(value%in%vec)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Sum=sum(Flag)) %>%
  filter(Sum>=1) %>%
  select(-c(Flag,Sum)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A01N  A01N  A01P  Null  Null  Null 
2 C09K  A61K  C09D  C08K  Null  Null 
3 A01D  A01D  A01D  A01D  A01D  Null
```

Or using `base R` with `apply()`:

```
#Code2
new <- df[apply(df,1,function(x) ifelse(sum(x %in% vec)>=1,1,0))==1,]
```

Output:

```
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
1 A01N A01N A01P Null Null Null
2 C09K A61K C09D C08K Null Null
4 A01D A01D A01D A01D A01D Null
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("A01N", "C09K", "A61K", "A01D", "E06A"), 
    V2 = c("A01N", "A61K", "A61P", "A01D", "Null"), V3 = c("A01P", 
    "C09D", "A61P", "A01D", "Null"), V4 = c("Null", "C08K", "A61K", 
    "A01D", "Null"), V5 = c("Null", "Null", "A61K", "A01D", "Null"
    ), V6 = c("Null", "Null", "A61K", "Null", "Null")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

If too many variables are producing issues, here a more simplified version of the code (Many thanks **GregorThomas**):

```
#Code1
new <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(sum(value %in% vec) > 0) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-id)

#Code2
new <- df[apply(df,1,function(x) sum(x %in% vec)>=1),]
```

Comment: If you don't mind a general comment, you... tend to do a lot of extra steps. I think `mutate(Flag=+(value%in%vec)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Sum=sum(Flag)) %>%
  filter(Sum>=1) %>%
  select(-c(Flag,Sum))` could be condensed to `group_by(id) %>% filter(sum(value %in% vec) > 0))`.

Comment: Similarly in your base version, =`ifelse(sum(x %in% vec)>=1,1,0))==1` is a long way to write `sum(x %in% vec) >= 1`.  You get the logical result you want, then you convert it to numeric with `ifelse()`, and then convert it back to logical with `== 1`. Skip the conversions.

Comment: @GregorThomas Great suggestions, let me add to the code, I use to do more steps to track what is happening!

Comment: I agree that temp variables (especially with nice names--which you have) can be useful in complicated processes. Especially if they're needed for more than one use. But in this case things are pretty straightforward and I think creating columns to use once and then drop makes the solution less clear, not more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one-liner in base R:

```
DF1[rowSums(DF1 %in% vec) > 0, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option in `base R` can be

```
subset(DF1, Reduce(`+`, lapply(DF1, `%in%`, vec)) > 0)
```

-output

```
#     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
#1 A01N A01N A01P Null Null Null
#2 C09K A61K C09D C08K Null Null
#4 A01D A01D A01D A01D A01D Null
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("A01N", "C09K", "A61K", "A01D", "E06A"), 
    V2 = c("A01N", "A61K", "A61P", "A01D", "Null"), V3 = c("A01P", 
    "C09D", "A61P", "A01D", "Null"), V4 = c("Null", "C08K", "A61K", 
    "A01D", "Null"), V5 = c("Null", "Null", "A61K", "A01D", "Null"
    ), V6 = c("Null", "Null", "A61K", "Null", "Null")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

vec <-  c('A01N','C09K','A01D')
```